# Select query to remote mssql from php, can only run certain queries

Tags: php, sql-server-2008, remote-access, execution-time

I am trying to query a remote `MSSQL` server from php. I connect fine using mssql_connect and run a simple query that gives me 3000 rows but if I try to run a query that gives me more than `100,000` rows it gives me a 500 internal server error. I tried increasing the `max_execution_time` for the php but with no avail. I don't know how to debug this since the connection is remote and don't have idea to go forward from here. Can anybody give any advice or solution to this problem.

Comment: Code or it didn't happen..

Comment: Anything in the error logs? Are you running IIS or apache?

Comment: I am connecting from a linux server to a remote Microsoft SQL server.

Comment: @Naruto : I just tried a simple query , if i run "select * from table where id like '%99%' " it gives me a result of 3000 rows and is fine. But if i try to run "select * from table where id like '%9%'" it gives me "500 internal server error" with a blank screen.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you guys, it turned out to be a memory_limit issue. I had to increase the memory_limit in php.ini and that fixed my problem. Thanks again for quick replies.

Comment: Fellow reviewers: this is an answer. OP explains what solved it for them, and there are no competing answers.